# Refactoring HTML5 page for responsive design

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I have the following JSFiddle:

> http://jsfiddle.net/3pMeK/

For the sake of this question, I'll refer to the components of that page as follows:

- `SignInHeaderHeader`: the text that reads "Sign In"
- `DescriptionText`: the text that reads "Sign in to use this incredible app." as well as the "Learn more." link
- `LoginForm`: the username/password fields, their respective lavels, and the sign in button
- `Footer`: the two text sections "Questions?..." and "Help Desk" at the very bottom

I am trying to refactor this to have a "responsive design", such that, as I make the browser window smaller, the following starts to happen:

1. `Header` remains at the top; and
2. The grey bar dividing the left and right portions of the page disappears; and
3. `LoginForm` inserts itself in between `Header` and `DescriptionText`; and
4. `Footer` remains at the bottom; and
5. No gaping/awkward whitespace between the 4 main components

Currently, when I make the browser smaller, I get the following behavior:

1. `Header` remains at the top; and
2. `DescriptionText` remains just below the `LoginForm`; and
3. The grey bar dividing the left and right portions of the page stays in place; and
4. `LoginForm` is rendered *below* `DescriptionText` and the grey division bar; and
5. Although `Footer` remains at the bottom; there is an "awkward" amount of whitespace between it and `LoginForm`

See for yourself in the fiddle by resizing the window.

#### Questions

1. Any idea how I could tweak/refactor the HTML/CSS there to resize/repaint the way I want it to. Is JSFiddle the right tool to use here? What are some common techniques used to accomplish what I need?
2. Although hacky and not very responsive, is it possible (at all - CS/JS, etc.) to reposition elements based on window size? So, something like: if `window.height < x then apply style y`, etc.?

Could this have anything to do with my use of `clearfix`:

```
<section class="content clearfix">
```

Comment: I would recommend to use mediaquerys like this `@media (min-width: 30em) and (max-width: 60em) { your css }`

Comment: If I had seen your question before, I would've closed it right away

Comment: Agree with @Mr.Alien. You are throwing away bounty on do it yourself questions. Your [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23969266/single-page-application-routing-w-crossroads-hasher-by-example) question is really very basic.

Comment: The question is did he get his answer...

Comment: @IAmYourFaja did you get your answer?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about refactoring code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### EDIT :

I implemented the below solution in your code, this should be the behaviour you are looking for :

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/3pMeK/4/)

I changed :

1. changed the order in the markup as follow ( also changed the `#sidebar` id to the class `.sidebar` as it now has two occurences):

   Header
   SignInHeaderHeader
   LoginForm
   DescriptionText
   Footer
2. changed CSS properties so it displays as in your fiddle
3. added the following media query with CSS properties that apply when the screen is smaller than 760px

.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
    .sidebar, #login_block{
        float:none;
        border:none;
        width:95%;
        padding-left:5%;
        text-align:left;
    } 
    .blurb p{
        margin:0;
    }
}
```

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER :

You may achieve this behaviour with CSS using **floats and media queries**.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/bRBR8/4/)

(resize the result window to se the elements rearange)

In the markup, the elements must have the order you want them to have when they are displayed in one column. Then you can use [floats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) to place them into two column when the screen is wide enough.

The [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) is used to

1. remove the float propereties
2. set apropriate width, paddings and margins
3. remove the vertical separator

*HTML :*

```
<header></header>
<section>
    <div id="signIn">Sign In</div>
    <form>
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" />
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="submit" value="SIGN IN" />
    </form>
    <div id="signInText">
        <p>Sign in to use this incredible app.</p>
        <p><a hre="#">Learn more</a></p>
    </div>
</section>
<footer>
    <p><strong>Questions?</strong>We're here to help. <a href="#">Help Desk</a></p>
</footer>
```

*CSS :*

```
body,html{
    margin:0;
}
header{
    height:58px;
    margin-bottom:40px;
    background: #071529;
}
section{
    overflow:hidden;
   margin-bottom:100px;
}
#signIn, #signInText{
    float:left;
    width:45%;
    text-align:right;

}
form{
    float:right;
    width:45%;
    border-left:1px solid #ccc;
    padding-left:5%;
}
form input,form,label{
    display:block;
}
footer{
    clear:both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  form, #signIn, #signInText{
    float:none;
        width:50%;
        padding:0;
        margin:0 auto;
        text-align:left;
  }
    form{
        border:none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add another @media like this

```
@media (max-width: 640px) {

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3pMeK/2/

**UPDATE**

To set up what you want, I can give you 2 suggestions:

**1- JQuery with the clone:**

```
$(".desc").clone().insertBefore("footer");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3pMeK/3/

Then use css to hide it in one part (desktop) and show it in mobile (vice-versa) but the one thing you do need would be a container div that i added called: "**desc**"..

...You can always just do it with *.blurb a* and *blurb p* if you could not add a container for whatever reason...but that is just more redundant work...

**2- Use flexbox** - but that will need a different approach with your css, but with flexbox, no need for JS, all you do is your container will be : `display: flexbox` and then your: `order: *`...here is a good start to see this in action:

[**LEARN FLEXBOX**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Awesome @Riskbreaker (+1) - thanks! However I don't see that `@media` in the link's CSS. Can you tell me where I can find it? Also, can you explain why it works? Thanks again!

Comment: in the fiddle it is in line 204 of the css

Comment: Thanks again @Riskbreaker (+1) - however in your link, when I resize the screen to make it smaller, the `DescriptionText` is still *above* the `LoginForm`, and it needs to be the other way around.  Thoughts on how to remedy this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make your webpage responsive i suggest using a responsive framework 
here are a couple of frameworks.

- [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/)
- [Bootstrap>](http://getbootstrap.com/)

I personally use foundation so i would tell you how it fits in for responsive design.

You can customize these frameworks according to your grid layouts and custom colors

here is a link to customize [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/develop/download.html#customizeFoundation)

Foundation has various visibility classes defined in CSS Which allows you to present content based on the Screen resolutions.

Find the documentation for visibility classes here -[LINK](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/visibility.html)

This [PAGE](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/kitchen_sink.html) includes every single Foundation element.

and coming to the solution for your question.

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3pMeK/10/).I suggest aligning elements 
in the center of the screen for mobiles.

> HTML

```
<head>
    <title>MyApp Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="logo"></div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section class="content clearfix">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <div class="blurb">
                    <h1>Sign In</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="login_block">
            <form id="fm1" class="fm-v clearfix" action="/login" method="post">
                <div class="row fl-controls-left">
                    <label for="username" class="fl-label">Username</label>
                    <input id="username" name="username" class="required" tabindex="1" accesskey="u" type="text" value="" size="25" autocomplete="false" />
                </div>
                <div class="row fl-controls-left">
                    <label for="password" class="fl-label">Password</label>
                    <input id="password" name="password" class="required" tabindex="2" accesskey="p" type="password" value="" size="25" autocomplete="off" />
                </div>
                <div class="row btn-row">
                    <input type="hidden" name="lt" value="FIZZBUZZ2949" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="execution" value="e6s1" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="_eventId" value="submit" />
                    <input name="submit" accesskey="l" value="SIGN IN" style="font-weight:600;" tabindex="4" type="submit" class="orangebutton" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
         <div class="sidebar">
            <div class="blurb">
                <p>Sign in to use this incredible app.</p>  <a href="http://myapp.example.com/docs">Learn more.</a>

            </div>
    </section>
    <footer class="clearfix">   <span><strong>Questions?</strong> We're here to help.</span>
<span><a href="mailto:helpdesk@myapp.example.com">Help Desk</a></span>

    </footer>
    <script src="/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

> CSS

```
html, body {
    font-family:'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    background: #f0f3f7;
}
section {
    margin: 0 10px 40px;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #03418F;
    margin: 0;
}
h1 sup {
    font-size: 16px;
}
p {
    font-size:20px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
a {
    color: #096dff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
header {
    height: 78px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    background: #071529;
}
header div.content {
    width:80%;
    height: 78px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
header div.logo {
    width:160px;
    height:78px;
    background-size: 147px 43px;
    margin-right:16px;
}
/* Media Queries */

/* header adjustments for phones and tablets */
 @media (max-width: 991px) {
    header {
        height: 58px;
    }
    header h1 {
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: 400;
    }
    header div.logo {
        width:28px;
        height:58px;
        background-size: 27px 34px;
        margin-right:16px;
    }
}
#login_block {
    float:right;
    padding-left: 5%;
    border-left: 1px solid #cccccc;
    width:45%;
    text-align:left;
    height:300px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
#login_block.centered {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 375px;
}
#login_block label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #333333;
}
#login_block input[type='text'], #login_block input[type='password'] {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #333333;
    display: block;
    width: 275px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
#login_block .forgot_password {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #096dff;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 1em;
    line-height: 41px;
}
#login_block .forgot_password:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#login_block .button_bar {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: right;
}
.blurb p {
    margin: 0 0 10px auto;
}
.sidebar .blurb {
    padding-right: 50px;
}
input.orangebutton {
    -webkit-background-clip: border-box;
    -webkit-background-origin: padding-box;
    -webkit-background-size: auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 1px 3px 0px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(244, 151, 48), rgb(219, 124, 14));
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(244, 151, 48), rgb(219, 124, 14));
    border-radius: 8px;
    border-image-repeat: stretch;
    border-style: none;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.247059) 0px 1px 3px 0px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    font-family:'Source Sans Pro', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 31px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    min-width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}
footer {
    padding-top: 125px;
    text-align: center;
}
footer span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
}
.errors {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #dc4a2e;
    margin: 1em 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}
.errors img {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
    .sidebar, #login_block{
        border:none;
        width:100%;
        padding:0px;
        text-align:center;
    } 
    .blurb p{
        margin:0;
    }
    #login_block input[type='text'], #login_block input[type='password'] {
    display:inline-block;        
    }
    input.orangebutton {
        float:none;
    }
    .sidebar .blurb {
        padding-right: 0px;
    }
    #login_block {
        float:none;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, it is possible and very easy to achieve. The only need you need to understand is Media Queries in CSS. *Keep in mind that IE 9 and lower, and some other browsers don't read CSS3 and you can't have responsive website on them (unless you do JS hacks).
2. Don't use JS to achieve that.

The first thing you need to do in your html part is to add this line in the HEAD attribute.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; 
              user-scalable=0;">`
That code disables the zoom-in and out on mobile devices and scales the website to full screen, so it looks like an app.

After that you need to specify the desired resolution to be checked in the CSS AND the device (i.e. sceen for monitor/laptop or device for all other devices) + orientation if you want.

Check the demo I did for you on jsfiddle.
**http://jsfiddle.net/Cowwando/w3m4g/**
Best regards,
Cowwando!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to come up with solutions in the fiddle attached.

[`\[http://jsfiddle.net/edDq7/\]\[1\]`](http://jsfiddle.net/edDq7/)

Apart from that if your not planning to use bootstrap or other grid systems then you need to en-corporate more media queries according to your design pattern. Hope this proves to be fruitful. Thanks

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>MyApp Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="logo"></div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section class="content clearfix">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div class="blurb">
            <h1>Sign In</h1>
            <p>Sign in to use this incredible app.</p>
            <a href="http://myapp.example.com/docs">Learn more.</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="login_block">
        <form id="fm1" class="fm-v clearfix" action="/login" method="post">
            <div class="row fl-controls-left">
                <label for="username" class="fl-label">Username</label>
                <input id="username" name="username" class="required" tabindex="1" accesskey="u" type="text" value="" size="25" autocomplete="false"/>
            </div>
            <div class="row fl-controls-left">
                <label for="password" class="fl-label">Password</label>
                <input id="password" name="password" class="required" tabindex="2" accesskey="p" type="password" value="" size="25" autocomplete="off"/>
            </div>
            <div class="row btn-row">
                <input type="hidden" name="lt" value="FIZZBUZZ2949" />
                <input type="hidden" name="execution" value="e6s1" />
                <input type="hidden" name="_eventId" value="submit" />
                <input name="submit" accesskey="l" value="SIGN IN" style="font-weight:600;" tabindex="4" type="submit" class="orangebutton"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </section>
    <footer class="clearfix">
        <span><strong>Questions?</strong> We're here to help.</span>
        <span><a href="mailto:helpdesk@myapp.example.com">Help Desk</a></span>
    </footer>
    <script src="/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    background: #f0f3f7;
}

section {
    margin: 0 10px 40px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #03418F;
    margin: 0;
}

h1 sup {
    font-size: 16px;
}

p {
    font-size:20px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

a {
    color: #096dff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header {
    height: 78px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    background: #071529;
}

header div.content {
    width:80%;
    height: 78px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

header div.logo {
    width:160px;
    height:78px;
    background-size: 147px 43px;
    margin-right:16px;
}

/* Media Queries */

/* header adjustments for phones and tablets */
@media (max-width: 991px) {

    header { 
        height: 58px;
    }

    header h1 {
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: 400;
    }

    header div.logo {
        width:28px;
        height:58px;
        background-size: 27px 34px;
        margin-right:16px;
    }
}

#login_block {
display: inline-block;
padding-left: 50px;
width: 50%;
float: right;
}

#login_block.centered {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 375px;
}

#login_block label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #333333;
}
#login_block input[type='text'],
#login_block input[type='password'] {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #333333;
    display: block;
    width: 275px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
#login_block .forgot_password {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #096dff;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 1em;
    line-height: 41px;
}
#login_block .forgot_password:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#login_block .button_bar {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

#sidebar {
float: left;
width: 40%;
text-align: left;
border-right: 1px solid #cccccc;
display: inline;
}

.blurb p {
    max-width: 375px;
    margin: 0 0 10px auto;
    float: left;
}

#sidebar .blurb {
    padding-right: 50px;
}

input.orangebutton {
    -webkit-background-clip: border-box;
    -webkit-background-origin: padding-box;
    -webkit-background-size: auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 1px 3px 0px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(244, 151, 48), rgb(219, 124, 14));
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(244, 151, 48), rgb(219, 124, 14));
    border-radius: 8px;
    border-image-repeat: stretch;
    border-style: none;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.247059) 0px 1px 3px 0px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 31px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    min-width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}

footer {
    padding-top: 125px;
    text-align: center;
}

footer span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
}

.errors {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #dc4a2e;
    margin: 1em 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

.errors img {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #sidebar {
    border-right: 0px solid #cccccc;
        width:100%;
   }
    #login_block {
width: 100%;
}
}
```

Comment: this doesn't have the desired behaviour : the text "sign in to this incredible app." should go under the form on resize

Comment: well that was in a rush so must have forgotten some points. I'll edit it shortly.

Answer (score 0):

another solution here ;)

http://jsfiddle.net/JZNjL/4/

> css

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    min-height: 640px;
}

html, body {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    background: #f0f3f7;
    min-width: 380px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #03418F;
    margin: 0;
}

a {
    color: #096dff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header {
    height: 58px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    background: #071529;
}

section.content {
    padding: 0 1%;
}

footer {
    bottom: 1em;
    padding: 0 10%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

footer span {
    display: block;
}

footer a {
    display: block;
    padding: .5em;
}

.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 0 0 3em 10%;
}

#sidebar .blurb p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 14.5em 0 0 0;
}

#sidebar .blurb a {
    padding: .5em .5em 0 .5em;
}

#sidebar .blurb p, #sidebar .blurb a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

#login_block {
    margin: -20em auto 0 auto;
}

#login_block label {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 .75em 10%;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #333333;
}

#login_block input[type='text'],
#login_block input[type='password'] {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #333333;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto .75em auto;
    padding: 0 0 .5em 0;
    width: 80%;
}

#login_block .forgot_password {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #096dff;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 41px;
}

#login_block .forgot_password:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#login_block .button_bar {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

input.orangebutton {
    -webkit-background-clip: border-box;
    -webkit-background-origin: padding-box;
    -webkit-background-size: auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 1px 3px 0px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(244, 151, 48), rgb(219, 124, 14));
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(244, 151, 48), rgb(219, 124, 14));
    border-radius: 8px;
    border-image-repeat: stretch;
    border-style: none;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.247059) 0px 1px 3px 0px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 31px;
    margin: .25em 0 0 10%;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    min-width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

        @media (min-width: 630px) {

    #login_block {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 0 0 1.5em;
        max-width: 42%;
    }

    #login_block label {
        margin: 0 0 .75em 0;
    }
    #login_block input[type='text'],
    #login_block input[type='password'] {
        width: 100%;
    }

    #sidebar {
        float: left;
        max-width: 50%;
        height: 300px;
        text-align: right;
        border-right: 1px solid #cccccc;
    }

    #sidebar .blurb {
        padding-right: 50px;
        text-align: right;
    }

    #sidebar .blurb p {
        padding: .5em 0 0 0;
    }

    #sidebar .blurb a {
        padding: .5em 0 0 .5em;
    }

    #sidebar .blurb p, #sidebar .blurb a {
        text-align: right;
    }

    input.orangebutton {
        margin: .25em 0 0 0;
    }

    footer {
        bottom: 1em;
    }
}
```