# Single page application routing w/ Crossroads & Hasher, by example

Tags: javascript, html, routes, single-page-application, crossroadsjs

I am trying to write my first single-page application. The idea is to have 1 HTML file that contains many `<div>` tags; where each `<div>` represents a single web "page". Then the application just shows 1 `<div>` at a time, and hides the others. In this way, as users navigate my app, I'm really just showing/hiding different "page" divs, and giving the illusion of a single page app.

Additional requirements are:

- This is an HTML5 app
- Each page div must map too its own bookmarkable URL (`http://myapp.example.com/#fizz`, `http://myapp.example.com/#buzz`, etc.)
- Singe each page div is bookmarkable, the app must work with the HTML5 history api

I decided on using Crossroads for routing, and Hasher for History. The other lead contender was AngularJS, but in the end I decided against AngularJS because it was too heavyweight for what I'm trying to do here, and seemed to have a steeper learning curve associated with it.

So far, my project has the following directory structure:

```
myapp/
    index.html
    myapp.js
    myapp.css
    signals.min.js          <-- Required by both Crossroads and Hasher
    crossroads.min.js
    hasher.min.js
```

The JSFiddle containing my `index.html`, `myapp.css` and `myapp.js` files is here:

> http://jsfiddle.net/Sxfms/2/

The idea is that the user can click one of the links in the "navbar" ("Home", "About", "Contact") and be brought to the "page" (div) representing that particular page.
As you can see, the default "page" should be `HOME`, meaning this is the only div you should be able to see. But all the page divs are visible, and none are hidden. And until I can get the page divs showing/hiding correctly, I can't really test routing/history functionality. Have I configured Crossroads/Hasher wrong somehow?

Comment: The multiple page abstraction is your thing. You have to implement it. Crossroads simply provides routing facility. It does not do what you are asking by default. You should try making more HTML5/CSS3 pages. CSS can handle the visibility. It is also pretty basic. If you would have searched here you would have found plenty of answers on how to do it.

Comment: Thanks @user568109 (+1): a few things: (1) i's my understanding that Crossroads handles routing and that Hasher handles history. If that's all they do, then someone just needs to tweak my code to show how to incorporate routing and history into my app, and I'll reward them the full bounty. And (2) I did research. In fact, if you look at my JS, you will be able to find almost the exact same functions/code as whats in the Crossroads docs. You say that there are plenty of answers on how to do what I'm asking; can you provide me links to 2 or 3 of them? Thanks again.

Comment: If your actual single page will include multiple pages. How would these pages be loaded ? Will they be all loaded when main page is loaded (from the same url). Or will these be remote pages/links of other url ?

Comment: Thanks again @user568109 (+1). The idea is to pull everything down with a single HTML file/request. Then just show/hide the correct "page" (`<div>`) that the user should be viewing. I need each "page" to correspond to a single, bookmarkable URL (i.e. the "Fizz" page, which might correspond to a `<div id="fizz">` element, and might be associated with the `http://myapp.example.com/#fizz` URL, etc.). On top of this, as the user navigates to multiple "pages", each bookmarkable URL needs to be pushed to the HTML5 history mechanism so forward/back buttons work.

Comment: So, to answer your questions: yes they will all be loaded when the main page loads, but only 1 "page" will be visible at any given time; all others will be hidden. When the main page loads it would be `http://myapp.example.com/` which would correspond to, say, the `<div id="home">` "page". If they were to click on the "About" link, the URL would become `http://myapp.example.com/#about` and the `<div id="home">` element would be hidden and the `<div id="about">` element would be shown.

Comment: Are Crossroads and Hasher required to get the full bounty if all other conditions are accomplished?

Comment: Thanks @FabianMebus (+1) - no they're definitely not required if they're not needed, but I would *enormously* appreciate a good explanation (especially for the 500) as to: (a) why they're not necessary, and (b) what use cases I *would* want to use a routing-based solution such as Crossroads.js. Thanks again!

Comment: Just curious as to why this is getting downvoted without anyone leaving a reason. My jsFiddle shows research, and this is a concrete programming question. If this is downvote-worthy, please explain.

Comment: LOL SO - multiple downvotes and still answered!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is a solution for your requirements. It is a really easy, lightweight approach without the need of any javascript just with the power of CSS. ;-)

The key of the whole approach is the CSS pseudo-class selector `:target`.

So let me first explain the concept of `:target`: The pseudo selector matches when the fragment identifier (or hash, *#content* for instance) in the URL and the `id` of an HTML element are the same. If we have a URL like `http://www.example.com/hallo.html#content` and an element with the `id="content"` the selector `#content:target { ... }` would match.

You can´t really see the URL in this **[fiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/Cxr73/)**, but you will in another example. Her is the code of the fiddle:

HTML:

```
<a href="#content">content</a>
<div id="content">
    Markup is poetry!
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 20px;
}

#content:target {
    background: lightblue;
}
```

The `:target` approach leads to this stripped down example to explain the *page-navigation-idea*: http://jsfiddle.net/Cxr73/1/ Again you can´t really see the URLs with the fragment identifier.

HTML:

```
<a href="#div1">div1</a>
<a href="#div2">div2</a>
<a href="#div3">div3</a>

<div id="div2">
    <div id="div3">
        <div class="div1Inner">content div1</div>
        <div class="div2Inner">content div2</div>
        <div class="div3Inner">content div3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.div2Inner, .div3Inner, 
#div2:target .div1Inner, #div3:target .div1Inner {
    display: none;
}

#div2:target .div2Inner, #div3:target .div3Inner {
    display: block;
}
```

Hide all `div`s that should not be displayed at first: `.div2Inner, .div3Inner { display: none;}`. So just `<div class="div1Inner">content div1</div>` is visible. Show the corresponding `div` when the fragment identifier is part of the URL: `#div2:target .div2Inner, #div3:target .div3Inner {display: block;}`. In the end you have to hide `div1` when `div2` or `div3` are visible: `#div2:target .div1Inner, #div3:target .div1Inner { display: none; }`. Combine the first and the last CSS selector and you get to the CSS shown above.

---

Some recommendations on your markup:

- As recommended by [the HTML5 spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/semantics.html#charset) (4.2.5.5 Specifying the document's character encoding), add your charset declaration early to avoid a potential [encoding-related security issue](https://code.google.com/p/doctype-mirror/wiki/ArticleUtf7) in IE. It should come in the first 1024 bytes.
- The `<center>` element was deprecated because it defines the presentation of its contents. For this purposes we have CSS.
- You are writing an **HTML5** app, so throw in some more semantic markup, elements like: `nav`, `header`, `section`, `footer`, etc.

---

Here you have the final approach of my ideas, with your CSS plus the `:target` selectors (starts at line 600) and what I consider a clean markup:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cxr73/2/
To finally see the fragment identifier plus the `:target` in action and for test purposes another URL: **[DEMO](http://so.fabianmebus.de/)** ... this demo will disappear in a few days, but the fiddle will stay.

I think that pretty much matches all your needs. Have fun!

Comment: Thanks @Fabian Mebus (+1) - this is an excellent and very elegant solution you've cooked up - thanks! **Three** followup items: (1) in you [DEMO](http://so.fabianmebus.de/) link, I see you have several new HTML5 tags (`<header>` for all pages, `<header>` for each page, `<section>` tags, etc.). Are these necessary for your solution to work, or did you just add them in there because they're HTML5 standards? In other words: can your CSS-based solution work outside of HTML5?

Comment: Then (2) Along those same lines, due to the CSS tricks required for this to work, are there any major browser versions that **wouldn't** be able to utilize this solution?

Comment: And finally (3) Can you please provide a quick blurb as to why `Crossroads.js` and routing in general isn't a good fit for this problem? I ask this because I seem to be misunderstanding what routing is, and I can't figure out why no one has been able to solve my problem with Crossroads. Thanks again (enormously) for this excellent answer - you're almost there!

Comment: Here you go: (1) The HTML5 elements are **not** necessary for the approach.
(2) The pseudo-class selector `:target` is now around for quite a long time. So the browser support is really good: [CSS3 selectors](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Atarget)

Comment: (3) I think you got the idea of *routing*. From my point of view `Crossroads.js` isn't in general a bad idea for your problem. It could have a much better documentation but why would you use a js library that requires another library and another plugin-library (hasher) to get the functionality you need, when you have all what you need already baked in the browser by default with just some lines of CSS?